# What is the best strategy to make an android app a trial version and then make a billing to unlock the app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have created my first android app and also implemented google licensing verification library into it.But the google LVL doesn't clearly states that how could I create a trial version of some days(say 3 days) for my app and then encourage the app user to buy the app.
As I want my app to run for 3 days with full functionality and then get disabled, while showing ads in trial version simultaneously.I am a beginner, seeking for someone's kind help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use flags in firebase remote config which you can update through firebase developer console. And set 3 days time binding from the day you uploaded your apk. I hope you understand.

Comment: thanks for replying, could you please elaborate the procedure ?

Comment: Visit firebase site and go through firebase remote config. You can see this: link https://droidmentor.com/how-to-update-your-app-using-firebase-remote-config/    and instead of update use your own flag.